# Facebook timeline no postings before 1970-01-01

Tags: facebook, unix-timestamp

I am administrating a company FB channel and currently I am trying to upload images of the brand's history. However, the upload feature freezes when I add an image or posting prior to 1970-1-1. I guess that's an issue with the database and related to the UNIX timestamp. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 4):

They are possibly using [epoch timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch) which can not contain dates prior to `1/1/1970`.  In anycase... This is a bug and should be reported to Facebook at their [Bug System](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, text posts and milestones can still be backdated before the Unix epoch, just not photos or videos.

I've had the same problem too for almost on two months. (Three bug reports didn't change anything!)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that milestones can be placed before 1970.  Thanks.  I have sent numerous bug reports to FB about the problem with photos with no results.  I guess no one over 42 works at Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Facebook is only using epoch timestamps to determine IF they want to save the date now.

Before I could set the date to before the UNIX timestamp, and they still appear correctly. However, if you want to change the date you can only choose a date of 1 January 1970 or later.

It amazes me that this bug still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you! posting milestones do work prior to 1/1/1970 including with photos. I added a milestone and tried both adding a photo (from the existing photo gallery) at the same time as posting the milestone and editing the milestone after it was posted to add the photo. Not tried video yet (as I don't have any moving images prior to 1970!). See FB for Swords Aviation. You do need to set the start date of your timeline prior to the date you want to post of course.